# C# - Displaying data from an XML file in a listbox from a Dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, listbox

I have an XML file with data in it and I want to display ONLY the 's of the organisation on one page and display the corresponding data (Address, ID) on another page. In Textboxes.

```
XML:
<Data>
  <Organisation>
<Name>Accident Compensation Corporation</Name>
    <ID> 022 12345678 </ID>
    <Address> 220 Bunny Street</Address>
    </Organisation>

  <Organisation>
    <Name>Test 2</Name>
    <Address> 50 Lambton Quay</Address>
    <ID> 021 8972468739 </ID>
  </Organisation>


</Data>
```

I have ripped this data into my C# and it is currently stored in a dictionary. In a separate class C# file.

```
public class Organisation
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string address;

    public Organisation(int id, string name, string address)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

}

This is what I have for loading the XML nodes and trying to display them in the listbox. However it cannot do this in the "try" and skips to the "Catch" displaying "Error"

```
                XmlNodeList names = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Name");
                XmlNodeList ids = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ID");
                XmlNodeList addresses = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Address");





                for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
                {

                    Organisation org = new Organisation(int.Parse(ids[i].InnerText), names[i].InnerText, addresses[i].InnerText);
                    Database.data.Add(org);

                }

                foreach (Organisation org in Database.data)
                {
                    directoryBox.Items.Add(org.name);

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Response.Write("ERROR");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code on the second page, placing them in textboxes

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            foreach (Organisation org in Database.data)
            {
                if (org.name.Equals(Session["Org"]))
                {
                    orgLabel.Text = org.name;
                      lastcontractorBox.Text = org.id.ToString();
                    buildingAddress.Text = org.address;
                }
            }
        }
```

The XML does work as I am able to display names using textbox1.Items.Add(names[i].InnerText);

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made two changes to your code posted.  1) I added to Organization a constructor with no parameters to make the xml linq simpler.  2) I changed ID from a int to a string since the id's have spaces in the number.

I suspect your xml has a namespace which may be the reason your code isn't working so I made my code very robust to handle cases where the are no namespaces and with xml that has namespaces.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<Data>" +
                  "<Organisation>" +
                "<Name>Accident Compensation Corporation</Name>" +
                    "<ID> 022 12345678 </ID>" +
                    "<Address> 220 Bunny Street</Address>" +
                    "</Organisation>" +
                  "<Organisation>" +
                    "<Name>Test 2</Name>" +
                    "<Address> 50 Lambton Quay</Address>" +
                    "<ID> 021 8972468739 </ID>" +
                  "</Organisation>" +
                "</Data>";

            XElement data = XElement.Parse(xml);

            List<Organisation> organizations = new List<Organisation>();

            organizations = data.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Organisation").Select(y => new Organisation()
            {
                name = (string)y.Element("Name"),
                address = (string)y.Element("Address"),
                id = (string)y.Element("ID")
            }).ToList();

            
        }
    }
    public class Organisation
    {
        public string id;
        public string name;
        public string address;

        public Organisation() { }
        public Organisation(string id, string name, string address)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
        }
    }
}
```